# Necessary and sufficient condition to obtain a $C^1$- diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

For $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R},$ let $\phi_{\alpha_,\beta}(u,v):=(u+\alpha \sin(v),v+\beta \sin(u)),u,v \in \mathbb{R}.$

1. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $\alpha,\beta$ so that $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ is a $C^1$-diffeormorphism on $\mathbb{R}^2.$
2. Prove that, under the conditions in 1., $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathbb{R}^2.$

For 1. it's necessary and sufficient to prove that $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ is injective and the Jacobian $J_{\phi_{\alpha,\beta}}(u,v)\neq 0$ for every $u,v \in \mathbb{R}.$

A quick computation shows that $J_{\phi_{\alpha,\beta}}(u,v)\neq 0$ for every $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $|\alpha \beta|<1.$

How to deal with the injectivity of $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$? What about 2., more precisely how to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \subset \phi_{\alpha,\beta}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I claim that $|\alpha\beta|<1$ is also sufficient for injectivity/surjectivity of $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$. Suppose $|\alpha\beta|<1$. We want to prove that for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, the system of equations \begin{align*}
u+\alpha\sin(v)&=x\\
v+\beta\sin(u) &= y
\end{align*}
has a unique solution $(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2$. Solve the second equation for $v$ and substitute into the first: $u+\alpha\sin(y-\beta\sin(u))=x$. If we have a solution $(u,v)$, $u$ must satisfy this equation. Consider $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, u\mapsto u+\alpha\sin(y-\beta\sin(u))$.  Then $u(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ and $$g'(u)=1-\alpha\beta\cos(y-\beta\sin u)\cos u,$$ so $g'(u)>0$ by assumption. Therefore $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is bijective and there is a unique $u\in\Bbb R$ satisfying $g(u)=x$. Then let $v$ be the unique number with $v+\beta\sin(u)=y$. Since $g(u)=x$, the equation $u+\alpha\sin(v)=x$ is also satisfied. So there is a solution and this argument also shows uniqueness, so $\phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ is bijective.

I am wondering if there is perhaps a less computational solution to this, for example if we assume the stronger condition $|\alpha|,|\beta|<1$, then the result is immediate from the contraction mapping principle.